# Автоматическое версионирование NPM пакетов

Tags: npm, непрерывная-интеграция

Не могу настроить автоматическое версионирование NPM пакетов. Использую gitlab pipline. У кого нибудь есть схема как автоматизировать паблишинг пакетов. Не обязательно на gitlab pipline. Буду рад любой реализации.